# assert_template test in rails. What folder does it look in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I am trying to write an assert_template test in my rails app. The view that I want rendered is in

app/views/plays/index.html.erb

Is my test just:

```
assert_template :index => "plays"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
# assert that the exact template "plays/index" was rendered
assert_template %r{\Aplays/index\Z}
```

`%r` means regular expression.